# Comparing files in two different TFS Collections

Tags: tfs

I have two files that I would like to compare, however they are each in a different TFS collection. How can I do the comparision within TFS ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comparison is never performed within TFS. All that TFS does is fetch the two files, then call a comparison utility.

You can do that by hand. Get the files, then go compare them.

Comment: Sorry to be not very specific, I was referring to doing this inside of Visual Studio 2010 Team Explorer with the built in compare functionality. Especially since I didn't find a way to be active in two collections at the same time.

Comment: I know what you're referring to, and there's clearly no way to do it from the IDE. You can't even reference two collections at the same time, can you?

Comment: You can start the compare from visual studio and then compare it with a file from another collection that is stored on your local disk

Answer (score 0):

TFS Integration Platform, that facilitate integration between external systems and Team Foundation Server.

You cam integrate  file or different TFS systems

http://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/